# Windows slowing down minimized processes

Tags: windows

When I minimize the window of a program that is performing some computation - is active, it slows down, if not becoming idle like the OS lowers its priority. 
When I maximize the window - restore it, it will seemingly resume the computation.

Means my application becomes inactive when put in background - minimized.

What may be the reason behind it?

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  Windows favors the threads that are owned by the process that owns the foreground window.  Keeps the user happy.

Comment: IS there anything I can do to bypass this feature for a particular application?

Comment: Windows will lower the priority which means that other programs can run but if you have CPU spare your program will still use that, and Windows definitely will not make your program stop.

Comment: It could be that http://i.stack.imgur.com/xueaR.png helps.